# Alternative queries in the same formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula for an alternative query based on a previous dropdown selection.

The A1 cell has the dropdown alternatives: "Nome" or "CPF."

In A2 goes the query parameter.

If A1 is equal "Nome" the query should be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("18aQSi4NHgSxwNYMktJXd3hBK-uDI7dZL8xToTStgaeQ";"Base!A:L")};"Select Col5 where Col1 = '"&B1&"'";0)="Sim";"";"Problema:");"Não está na base de dados")
```

If A1 is equal "CPF" the query should be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("18aQSi4NHgSxwNYMktJXd3hBK-uDI7dZL8xToTStgaeQ";"Base!A:L")};"Select Col5 where Col4 = '"&B1&"'";0)="Sim";"";"Problema:");"Não está na base de dados")
```

The only difference among the queries is in the WHERE clause. The first one points to **Col1**, and the last to **Col4**.

I need to merge both queries in just one formula. Is it possible?

The data sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18aQSi4NHgSxwNYMktJXd3hBK-uDI7dZL8xToTStgaeQ/edit#gid=0), and the search box is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxlZTtJpYfG5rhZ1aBDjMCMKG96LK73RZc9TLEc5zfs/edit#gid=0).

Comment: I'll give you a tip, as this is the English question area, don't use ```;``` because when they try to use your formula, it will give an error.

So when publishing here, use the international template instead of ```;``` use ```,```. Example: ```=FUNCTION(part1,part2,part3)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you confirm both of your `query`'s are working properly, and you want to swap between a query based on a cell, adding an *if statement* by combining both `query`'s will do, so that your `query` become the value if `true`. Please try it. It is quite simple to do:

```
=if(A1="Nome",(IFERROR(IF(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("18aQSi4NHgSxwNYMktJXd3hBK-uDI7dZL8xToTStgaeQ","Base!A:L")},"Select Col5 where Col1 = '"&B1&"'",0)="Sim","","Problema:"),"Não está na base de dados")),
IF(A1="CPF",(IFERROR(IF(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("18aQSi4NHgSxwNYMktJXd3hBK-uDI7dZL8xToTStgaeQ","Base!A:L")},"Select Col5 where Col4 = '"&B1&"'",0)="Sim","","Problema:"),"Não está na base de dados")),""))
```